# Split by newline returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text file that I'm separating by a new line.

```
$.get("2016-05-06.log", function(data){
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
       var piece = elem.split("]");
       console.log(n, ": ", elem);
    });
```

However, the first item in the array `lines`, so where `n = 0`, is returning undefined. Is this array not zero-indexed? Or am I missing something?

EDIT: Here's a sample of whats in my log file.

```
[Wed May 04 13:48:44 2016] [error] [client 0.0.0.0] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for getTypeOptionList(), called in /var/www/...proposal.php on line 969 and defined in /var/www/Intranet2/trunk/contracts/functions.php on line 149, referer: http://intranet/...
[Wed May 04 13:48:44 2016] [error] [client 0.0.0.0] PHP Warning:  /var/www/...proposal.php on line 1048 and defined in /var/www/Intranet2/trunk/contracts/functions.php on line 373, referrer: http://intranet/...
```

Comment: chances are that data doesn't contain what you expect for it to.  there isn't really enough information here for us to help yet.  open developer tools (hit f12 or ctrl+y on most machines,) set a breakpoint on the second line by clicking at the far left edge in the line numbers, and reload the page.  it should halt at the breakpoint.  then when you select data and hover over the selection, you should be able to see what's inside, giving you a way to sanity check your assumptions.

Comment: Does file contain binary data? What is file type? `text/x-log` ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes it is a text file.

Comment: @MattBall It's just text, i'll edit with a sample of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works properly.

There must be many reasons.

Seems like Your file has utf-8 BOM element or something else.

To prove it have some test.log file and write data one after other, and then check Your code. 
Maybe You'd better to check line var for emptyness.

```js
$(function() {
  $.get("http://num8er.me/test.log", function(data){
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    for(var n = 0; n < lines.length; n++) { 
       var line = lines[n].toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
       if(line != '') {
         alert(n + ": " + line);
       }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I was getting "undefined" messages and was therefore checking if `lines != NULL`. Realized that this is because I was trying to split the blank line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be possible in JavaScript. I get the following results on Node.js v10.11.0 on Windows 10 using the WebStorm IDE to evaluate expressions. The string "|\n" splits into 3 parts with the RegularExpression /^(\w|\s)*\|/,  the second part being undefined.

This is unlike in your example where your first element was undefined, so it's not simply about the beginning of the array or something. And I don't have newline in my pattern, but in the string being split, and it's not the first character in the string. So in summary your example does not seem to be the only case where it can happen.

```
"|\n" . split( /^(\w|\s)*\|/ ) [0]  // -> ""
"|\n" . split( /^(\w|\s)*\|/ ) [1]  // -> undefined
"|\n" . split( /^(\w|\s)*\|/ ) [2]  // -> "\n"
```

I would have thought that split() always returns an Array of Strings. But seems not always. Don't count on it never being undefined.